# VTK: Trying to select visible cells in area with vtkrubberbandpick & vtkHardwareSelector

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm trying to do an area pick of visible cells on an object using a subclass of vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandPick. I've got everything working, except for one problem: If I change the perspective of the camera at all, the pick no longer works correctly. It just picks seemingly random cells on the object, instead of the ones inside the rubberband.

My LeftButtonUp in my InteractorStyle is basically like this:

```
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkHardwareSelector> selector = vtkSmartPointer<vtkHardwareSelector>::New();
        selector->SetRenderer(this->Interactor->GetRenderWindow()->GetRenderers()->GetFirstRenderer());
        unsigned int windowSize[4];

        windowSize[0] = StartPosition[0] < EndPosition[0] ? StartPosition[0] : EndPosition[0]; // xmin
        windowSize[1] = StartPosition[1] < EndPosition[1] ? StartPosition[1] : EndPosition[1]; // ymin
        windowSize[2] = StartPosition[0] < EndPosition[0] ? EndPosition[0] : StartPosition[0]; // xmax
        windowSize[3] = StartPosition[1] < EndPosition[1] ? EndPosition[1] : StartPosition[1]; // ymax

        selector->SetArea(windowSize);
        selector->SetFieldAssociation(vtkDataObject::FIELD_ASSOCIATION_CELLS);
        selector->CaptureBuffers();
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkSelection> selection = selector->GenerateSelection();


        vtkSmartPointer<vtkExtractSelection> extractSelection = vtkSmartPointer<vtkExtractSelection>::New();
        extractSelection->SetInputData(0, actor->GetMapper()->GetInput());
        extractSelection->SetInputData(1, selection);

        extractSelection->Update();

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> selected = vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>::New();
        selected->ShallowCopy(extractSelection->GetOutput());

        _faceSelectMapper->SetInputData(selected);
```

Do I need to do some kind of transformation somewhere? Do I need to somehow update the hardwareselector? I have searched everywhere but I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

Due to the clipping window effected part through the data is changing, you are getting different results every time you change camera orientation. You need to check whether the mode is selection or orientation like below

```
#define VTKISRBP_ORIENT 0
#define VTKISRBP_SELECT 1

if(this->CurrentMode == VTKISRBP_SELECT){
    // interactor codes...
}
```

https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Picking/HighlightSelection